# How to convert percentage (Indian) grade to German grades

Tags: university, germany, grades

What is the exact procedure for converting percentage grade to the german grading system. As of now what I understand is that the conversion is done by the modified bavarian formula. Is the average percentage score directly converted using the formula, or is the score weighted/adjusted from the data in transcripts before it is converted? If the grades are directly converted  using the formula then it seems US grading system has an unfair advantage over systems that use a percentage system where a score around 60-70% is very high, but still has some gap from the 'maximum possible grade'!

I am particularly worried because my University follows a very tight grading system (especially for arts courses) such that a first division (which is the best division) is a score above 60%, but the bavarian formula uses highest possible grade that can be obtained while calculating the converted score. Thus in my case 100% is the theoretical limit but in reality the highest attained grade in the entire university for my course tends to be in the mid seventies. The agency called uni-assist which is responsible for converting the grades have been giving very evasive answers when asked about the procedure.

It would be great if someone here knows a bit more about the procedure and is willing to share their knowledge.

Comment: Each university can convert as they wish, there have been several questions on here about this, you should check them.

Comment: Ask the German university. Maybe they don't use a complicated formula, but grades are converted via discussion with you.